# scanning plot through a large data file using python

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, plot

I have a large (10-100GB) data file of 16-bit integer data, which represents a time series from a data acquisition device. I would like to write a piece of python code that scans through it, plotting a moving window of a few seconds of this data. Ideally, I would like this to be as continuous as possible.

The data is sampled at 4MHz, so to plot a few seconds of data involves plotting ~10 million data points on a graph. Unfortunately I cannot really downsample since the features I want to see are sparse in the file.

matplotlib is not really designed to do this. It is technically possible, and I have a semi-working matplotlib solution which allows me to plot any particular time window, but it's far too slow and cumbersome to do a continuous scan of incrementally changing data - redrawing the figure takes several seconds, which is far too long.

Can anyone suggest a python package or approach do doing this?

Answer (score 0):

[PyQtGraph](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/) is faster than Matplotlib but I don't know if it can plot 10 million points a second. It does also include multiple methods to down-sample your data so one of them might still be useful to you. Note that it requires Qt and PyQt.

Still, you have between 5e9 and 5e10 data samples. If you can simultaneously plot 
10 million of them, this still means making between 500 and 5000 plots. Are you really going to inspect them all visually? You might consider to implement some kind of feature detection.

Comment: Oh there is lots of feature detection available to me, but I would like to have a quick scan through the data to see if it's useful before applying more complex algorithms. Downsampling is not really an option here (might be able to get away with a factor of 3 or so).

Answer (score 0):

Something that has worked for me in a similar problem (time varying heat-maps) was to run a batch job of producing several thousands such plots over night, saving each as a separate image. At 10s a figure, you can produce 3600 in 10h. You can then simply scan through the images which could provide you with the insight you're looking for.

Comment: Unfortunately I need quasi-real-time processing for my application (mainly a quick scan through the file to help set up more detailed analysis).